# Wide character print even with utf8 encoding

Tags: perl, utf-8, character-encoding, mechanize

I am getting a `"Wide character in print"` warning even with encoding set to `utf8`:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
$mech = new WWW::Mechanize;
$mech->get("http://www.ilo.org/dyn/triblex/triblexmain.fullText?p_lang=en&p_judgment_no=88&p_language_code=FR");
$mech->save_content("output.html", binmode => ':encoding(UTF-8)');
```

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you certain it's this line that's giving the warning? I don't see how that's possible

Comment: Are you saying it's not possible because of `binmode => ':encoding(UTF-8)'` ?  The warning is on a line in Mechanize.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

looks like `:encoding(UTF-8)` wasn't properly understood.

```
$mech->save_content($filename, binmode => ':raw:utf8');
```

should work

UPD: information on binmode directives (Perl IO layers) can be found here: http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html

Comment: What are all the options to use for `binmode` ?

Comment: what do you mean by 'all options'? when you  use 'binmode' you say to Perl interpreter to treat filehandle as binary rather than text and 'options' you mentioned are actually directives on how to deal with line endings, character encoding and so on on this particular filehandle

Comment: So which directives can you use?  You mentioned `:raw:utf8`. Which other ones can be used?

Comment: they are also called I/O layers and they're poorly documented AFAIK. Something could be found at: http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html

Comment: `:encoding(UTF-8)` is listed there. Why isn't it understood if `:raw` and `:utf8` are?

Comment: @ikegami not clear. Could be a peculiarity of the WWW::Mechanize implementation

Comment: @sotona See my updated code in the question for a demonstration of the problem.

Comment: @CJ7 I see, but using cURL or desktop browser I see 'question-mark diamonds'  instead  of letters with diacritic marks.  so  maybe the problem is in the source, not destination?

Comment: @sotona So you experienced a `wide character in print` warning in perl?

Comment: with your example - no. however I was able to model this issue and indeed with `binmode => ':encoding(UTF-8)` it complains to wide character in print

Comment: anyway everyone suggests to upgrade WWW::Mechanize, LWP and HTTP::Request to get rid of this error

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the warning you're getting. If I run the code you have shown as it stands I get no warning at all. But there does appear to be something wrong with the site. I wrote this program which uses `LWP` and skips `WWW::Mechanize` altogether

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

use LWP;

use constant URL => 'http://www.ilo.org/dyn/triblex/triblexmain.fullText?p_lang=en&p_judgment_no=88&p_language_code=FR';

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $res = $ua->get(URL);

print $res->headers_as_string, "\n";

my $n = 0;
for my $chr ( unpack '(A1)*', $res->decoded_content ) {
    my $ord = ord $chr;
    printf "%4d: %04x\n", ++$n, $ord if $ord >= 0x7f;
}
```

The response has perfectly reasonable headers, but all of the accented non-ASCII characters in the body of the response are [**Unicode FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER**](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm)

That shouldn't cause a *Wide character in print* error, but it is certainly wrong. Please check that you have the latest versions of `LWP` and `WWW::Mechanize`

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Date: Thu, 17 Mar 2016 23:15:12 GMT
Via: 1.1 www.ilo.org
Server: Oracle-Application-Server-10g/10.1.3.5.0 Oracle-HTTP-Server
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Length: 10132
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Client-Date: Thu, 17 Mar 2016 23:15:12 GMT
Client-Peer: 193.134.195.36:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
Title: Jugement No 88 (TAOIT) - Tribunal administratif

   1: fffd
   2: fffd
   3: fffd
   4: fffd
   5: fffd
   6: fffd
   7: fffd
   8: fffd
   9: fffd
  10: fffd
... etc. to
 316: fffd
 317: fffd
 318: fffd
 319: fffd
 320: fffd
 321: fffd
```

Comment: Maybe it is the version of `perl` or `Mechanize`.  This is the warning I get: `Wide character in print at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.3/WWW/Mechanize.pm line 2044.`

Comment: Yes. As I said, please check the versions of `WWW::Mechanize` and `LWP`. You may also want to check `Encode`. You can check with `perl -MEncode -E"say $Encode::VERSION"` etc. What version of Perl are you running?

Comment: perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for sun4-solaris

Comment: I am testing on Perl v5.22.1 for Windows, and have `Encode` v2.78 `LWP` v6.15 and `WWW::Mechanize` v1.75

Comment: But remember that all you will get by fixing this is that the warnings will go away. The `www.ilo.org` web server is sending useless Unicode characters, and that has to be fixed

Comment: I have `Encode` v2.49, `LWP` v6.13 and `WWW::Mechanize` v1.72

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106666/discussion-between-borodin-and-cj7).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue downloading .xlsx files (with Mechanize) and subsequently reading them with Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX. I was getting the "Wide Character" warning during $mech->save_content() and subsequently getting read errors with ParseXLSX ("format error: bad signature" & "Can't open file as a zip file" errors). The Mechanize documentation says that adding the 'binary -> 1' option to the save_content method is the "safest" way to insure byte-by-byte copying of the content. I tried it and it worked! The binmode options mentioned here did NOT work.